# Mongoose(mongoDB) Linking multiple schema's

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im relatively new to `MongoDB` and `Mongoose`. Im much used to MySQL so in used to inner joining tables on calls. Ive read a lot that you can link two `Mongoose Schemas` to achieve the same outcome. How would like like the two schemas together to when I make a call to get a chore by id it'll return the chore and then for the `assignedTo` & `createdBy` have the user scheme data for the said `userId`?

**Chore Schema**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ChoreSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  desc: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  time: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  reaccurance: {
    type: [{
      type: String,
      enum: ['Daily', 'Weekly', 'Bi-Weekly', 'Monthly']
    }]
  },
  reward: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  retryDeduction: {
    type: Number,
    required: false
  },
  createdDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  createdBy: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  dueDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  },
  status: {
    type: [{
      type: String,
      enum: ['new', 'pending', 'rejected', 'completed', 'pastDue']
    }],
    default: ['new']
  },
  retryCount: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
    required: false
  },
  rejectedReason: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  },
  familyId: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  assignedTo: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
    default: ""
  }
});

let Chores = module.exports = mongoose.model('Chores', ChoreSchema);
module.exports.get = function (callback, limit) {
  Chores.find(callback).limit(limit);
};
```

**User Schema**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  lastName: {
      type: String,
      required: true
  },
  role: {
    type: [{
        type: String,
        enum: ['Adult', 'Child']
      }]
  },
  birthday: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  },
  familyId: {
      type: String,
      required: true
  },
  balance: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0.00
  }
});

let Users = module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema);
module.exports.get = function (callback, limit) {
  Users.find(callback).limit(limit);
};
```

Im trying to link `ChoreSchema.createdBy` & `ChoreScheme.assignedTo` by `UserSchema._id`

How I make the call in Node.js:

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
  Chore.get(function(err, chore) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json({
      message: 'Chore List',
      data: chore
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Mongoose has a more powerful alternative called populate(),
> which lets you reference documents in other collections.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Here is how you can link `ChoreSchema.createdBy` and `ChoreScheme.assignedTo` by `UserSchema._id`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema, Types } = mongoose;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: { type: String, required: true },
    ...
})

var ChoreSchema = new Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    ...
    //The ref option is what tells Mongoose which model to use during population
    assignedTo: { type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Users' },
    createdBy: { type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Users' },
})

let Chores = mongoose.model('Chores', ChoreSchema);
let Users = mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema);
```

Then in your `express` route handler you can populate `assignedTo` & `createdBy` like this

```
router.get('/chores/:id', function (req, res) {
    const choreId = req.params.id;
    Chores.find({ _id: choreId })
        .populate('createdBy') // populate createdBy
        .populate('assignedTo') // populate assignedTo
        .exec(function (err, chore) {
            if(err) {
                return res.send(err)
            }
            res.json({ message: 'Chore List', data: chore });
        });
})
```

Comment: @moutso090 how would i do this with a simple `/chores` call to get ALL chores and still populate these datapoints?

Comment: @CharlesL. To get all chores and still populate the datapoints call `Chores.find()` without arguments. Like in my answer just remove `{ _id: choreId }` from the `find()` method